# combine sublists in racket

Tags: list, racket

I am working on a problem in racket and I am most of the way to the solution, however, my program is returning me this:

```
(list
 (list 'a (list 'red 'circle))
 (list 'a (list 'red 'square))
 (list 'a (list 'green 'circle))
 (list 'a (list 'green 'square))
 (list 'a (list 'blue 'circle))
 (list 'a (list 'blue 'square))
 (list 'b (list 'red 'circle))
 (list 'b (list 'red 'square))
 (list 'b (list 'green 'circle))
 (list 'b (list 'green 'square))
 (list 'b (list 'blue 'circle))
 (list 'b (list 'blue 'square)))
```

instead of this:

```
(list
 (list 'a 'red 'circle)
 (list 'a 'red 'square)
 (list 'a 'green 'circle)
 (list 'a 'green 'square)
 (list 'a 'blue 'circle)
 (list 'a 'blue 'square)
 (list 'b 'red 'circle)
 (list 'b 'red 'square)
 (list 'b 'green 'circle)
 (list 'b 'green 'square)
 (list 'b 'blue 'circle)
 (list 'b 'blue 'square))
```

I am trying to find an elegant solution to add on to my current program to change the output, but have hit a roadblock. I have tried messing with the append function to no avail. There could also be times where there is more than one sublist I have to undo as well such as the first element being:

```
(list 'a (list 'red (list 'circle)))
```

rather than:

```
(list 'a 'red 'circle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can get the output you want: you can either modify your program itself to build the list you want, *or* you can take the result of your program and transform it to your desired output. Since there is no code in your question for the former, I will suggest a solution to the latter.

The built-in [`flatten`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=flatten#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._flatten%29%29) exists in Racket that does just what you want:

```
(flatten (list 'a (list 'red 'circle))
=> '(a red circle)
(flatten (list 'a (list 'red (list 'circle)))
=> '(a red circle)
```

or, you can even transform the list of lists by doing:

```
(map flatten '((a (red circle))
               (a (red square))
               (a (green circle))
               (a (green square))
               (a (blue circle))
               (a (blue square))
               (b (red circle))
               (b (red square))
               (b (green circle))
               (b (green square))
               (b (blue circle))
               (b (blue square))))
```